# Almost Jensen's Inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b$ and $c$ three positive reals numbers such that $abc=1$. Define the function $f$ by $f(x)=\frac{^1}{1+(n-1)x^n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that

$$a^2f\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+b^2f\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)+c^2f\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)\ge\frac{3}{n}$$

I tried Jensen's inequality but got nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: According to your assumption, this is not true  e.g. take $ a=b =c=0.1$ then we have $$3a^2f (1)=\frac{3a^2}{n} \not\ge \frac{3}{n} $$

Comment: Your example doesn't fulfill the condition $abc=1$.

Comment: Right, I didn't take care from this condition. Sorry